# Hosting company lost my domain

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration

My hosting company charges an annual fee for domain renewals (standard enough so far). I have paid up every year, including this year. However, for some unknown reason, they let my domain lapse and it was taken by some random Asian gambling site. I’ve had the domain since 2015, no massive traffic or anything but had almost 100 incoming links (writer/blog website, also used to sell a novel I wrote).

It has been months now back and forth with customer service, no one seems to want to give me a straight answer as to how this happened, or if they even know what happened. Their team has apparently been in touch with the registry but to no avail, and said their best chance is to wait until Oct 2024 when it’s up for renewal again to try and get it back.

What are my options here? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Domain is neiltr.com

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, the customer service team sent me the following:

“When the invoice was paid for your domain renewal, our system sent the renewal request to our upstream registry partner to complete the renewal. However, what appears to have happened was that this request was not processed successfully. It could be that there were temporary network issues or similar at the time. Additionally, we had not received any notice that this transaction was not successful. Our system did not provide a notification that this failed, and the domain remained active, so no flags that indicated this failure existed.

Instead of the domain becoming expired/in redemption/deleted, the domain was immediately auctioned to another party. Because of this, we've raised a complaint with ICANN to obtain counsel and resolution on the matter.”

Comment: Is your registrar [accredited by ICANN](https://www.icann.org/en/accredited-registrars)? I think you can file a complaint through them, if you want to. It also lists [5 things you should know](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/registrant-about-errp-2018-12-07-en). However, your registrar should have pointed this out to you.

Comment: Digging deeper in to @KIKOSoftware's source, here are some additional ICANN links that may be relevant: [About Lost Domain Names](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/lost-domain-names), [Submitting a Complaint to ICANN Contractual Compliance](https://www.icann.org/compliance/complaint). Notably, the `.com` TLD *is* an ICANN-compliant TLD.